# Call a function while setting class properties

Tags: php, class, properties

Is accessing functions while setting class properties possible in PHP (5.2 or 5.3) ?

```
class DAOClass {

   var $someProperty = SomeObject::staticMethod('readConfigProperty');

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible because you have to initialize the properties with constant values. It isn't even possible to do this:

```
var $property = array(0);
```

The way to do what you want to do is inside the class constructor:

```
class DAOClass {

    var $someProperty;

    public function __construct() {
         $this->someProperty = SomeObject::staticMethod('readConfigProperty');
    }
}
```

As a side note, using `var` to declare properties [is not the preferred way](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php). Use `private`, `protected` or `public` instead to declare a property along with its visibility (`var` defaults to `public`).

Comment: `var` was forgiven and undeprecated.

Answer (score 2):

No. In the class declaration you *define* properties. You do not *assign* them anything. Everything after the `=` must be a literal constant. Method/function calls are expressions and cannot be used there.