# can't use __() in AppController cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

When I use the `__()` function for translating a message in the AppController I get the following error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'

This is my code:

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Acl',
    'Auth' => array(
         'authError' => __('Did you really think you are allowed to see that?'),        
         'authorize' => array(
            'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
        )
    )
);
```

`__()` is supposed to be a global function, right?. Because it seems PHP is not calling it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP localization of Auth component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289396/cakephp-localization-of-auth-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an issue of php but a very basic php error. The parser is already telling you this.

You can't use functions in a property declaration.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 1):

You can't call functions in a property declaration, hence the error.  [Call a function while setting class properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475228/call-a-function-while-setting-class-properties)

You'll have to translate authError in another place in the app.  Perhaps beforeRender or beforeFilter would work.